# How to judge a class whether System's or Custom's?

Tags: ios, objective-c

everyone!

How to judge a Class whether System's or Custom's?

The Custom's Class is inherit from NSObject, too.

How to differentiate？

Please，THX～

Supplement，like this:

```
- (void)aaaa:(Class)aCustomClass
{
    id instance = [[aCustomClass alloc] init];
    NSArray * array = GET_A_CLASS_ALL_PROPERTY(aCustomClass);  //it is a NSString array.
    for (NSString * property in array)
    {
        Class classOfTheProperty = GET_THE_PROPERTY_CLASS(property);  //the property's Class.
        if ([classOfTheProperty isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
        {
            [instance setObject:@"1234" forKey:property];
        }
        else if (IS_CUSTOM_CLASS)  //CUSTOM_CLASS maybe has less one hundred.
        {
            //Continue inner.
            [self aaaa:classOfTheProperty];
        }
        else if (IS_SYSTEM_CLASS)  //SYSTEM_CLASS definite has more than hundreds.
        {
            //Do Nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by "System" or "Custom"? There's no strict line there, especially because classes are created at runtime.

Comment: I think he means how to tell if a Class is included in a framework provided by Apple vs. a third party?

Comment: If custom's Class, I must to enumerate its property, and map to a NSDictionary, the system Class is not. The custom Class maybe has an other custom Class.

Comment: This should used in data-model-layer, likes ORM. Json string covert to a custom Entity. But the Entity is unknown to me now, and I should not known later, because I develop the supply framework.

Comment: Perhaps the classes you wish to enumerate should all conform to some protocol marking it as one of your entities. The protocol doesn't need any methods or properties. Use it as a marker.

Comment: Thanks. Solve my question has two way, one is inherit from custom root Class, one is your's, accord a empty protocol, but I think these not the prefect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the class was loaded from your app's main bundle and not from a framework:

```
    Class c = ...
    NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleForClass:c];
    if (b == [NSBundle mainBundle]) {
        // Custom class ...
    }
```

Comment: Bingo, Thank you very much, I want just this!

Answer (score 0):

You can check class by creating it's obj and checking it with method **isKindOfClass**

```
if ([element isKindOfClass:[customClassName class]]) //check wether object is of custom class
{
    // Custom Class
} 
else if ([element isKindOfClass:[systemClassName class]])
    // System Class
}
```

Comment: No, Thanks. I want to judge the Class, not instance, and the systemName has hundreds, the "else if" must be hundreds.